# Postgres plpgsql Java Set<> equivalent

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I have a plpgsql stored procedure which gets a list of uuids with duplicates and I want to create a set of unique uuids before I use it in a select statement.
Is there a data structure equivalent to Java's Set<> where I can add all the uuids and access it at the end to get a minimal list of all uuids?
I know I can do so with a temp table but I thought that if there is a specialized data structure it can provide better performance.
I can't do it in the application level for other reasons.

Comment: You can use an array

Comment: Wouldn't an array allow duplicates? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Yes it would, but if you use it in a select statement like e.g. `where uuid_column = ANY (your_array_of_uuids)` it wouldn't matter.

Comment: If my original list has 10k uuids while the minimal set contains only 200, won't a select with 200 values work faster? @ a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: It probably will, the question is if you can measure the difference. You can use a combination of `unnest()` and `array_agg(distinc)` to extract the unique values from the array - but that is essentially the same work the server would do when you _use_ the array, so I'm not sure if that would make things faster.

Comment: Thanks! I'll start with your initial suggestion. If you want you can write it as an answer and I'll accept it. @a_horse_with_no_name